# How to extend AbstractScheduledService.Scheduler

Tags: java, guava

I am trying to extend `AbstractScheduledService.Scheduler` so that I can use a schedule that stores initial delay and period in instance variable.

I am trying with the following

```
public class ScannerScheduler extends AbstractScheduledService.Scheduler {

    @Override
    public final Future<?> schedule(AbstractService as, 
        ScheduledExecutorService ses, Runnable task) {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
                 .scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
}
```

But the compiler still complains with:

> ScannerScheduler is not abstract and does not override abstract method
>   schedule(AbstractService,ScheduledExecutorService,Runnable) in
>   Scheduler

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post a link to the Javadoc or project page of whatever's providing this base class; I looked up the Guava Javadocs, and I'm not seeing `schedule` on it.

Comment: @chrylis: It is there: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html

Comment: @IgorRodriguez Not in that link you provided, it isn't. There's a class `AbstractScheduledService.Scheduler`, but it directly extends `Object`, and there's no `schedule` method on it.

Comment: From the class' javadoc: " If more flexibility is needed then consider subclassing AbstractScheduledService.CustomScheduler."

Answer (score 4):

**REVISED**

The `Scheduler` class has a `private` constructor, which means that you cannot extend it without modifying the Guava library code.

You therefore need to take the alternative approach suggested by the javadocs.

> If more flexibility is needed then consider subclassing `CustomScheduler`.

---

(The compilation error is a bit misleading in this case ... but the bottom line is that the `extend` approach will not work.)

Comment: This is part of the problem, but the error message indicates that the compiler *is* finding the `schedule` method and is complaining that it's not overridden.

Comment: +1 for this answer.  You're not intended to be able to subclass the `Scheduler` type, and this is just the compiler flailing.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answers! IMHO this class is overcomplicated with regards to scheduling. I'll rewrite my own.

Comment: @Ste The CustomScheduler subclass was designed to be easy to use (but obviously we have failed at least in terms of discoverability).  Could you let me know what features you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The method `Future<?> schedule(AbstractService service, ScheduledExecutorService executor,
        Runnable runnable)` of `AbstractScheduledService` is final, and thus cannot be overridden.

See line 393 here: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.java?r=d0f4023bd9027b21d9ef3f8077651ad0d2c2275d

From the code there, it seems that the same method signature in the class `Scheduler` can be overridden, don't know if that helps you though:

```
new Scheduler() {
    @Override
    public Future<?> schedule(AbstractService service, ScheduledExecutorService executor,
        Runnable task) {
      return executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, initialDelay, delay, unit);
    } 
  };
```

Comment: thank you! the design of the class is a bit cumbersome given the limited scheduling capabilities at the end (just fixedDelay and fixedRate). I will go for a simpler implementation.